# Networking with Kernel Bypass in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, real-time

Has anyone figured it out how to do Kernel bypass in Java? Any hello world somewhere or this is rocket science?

Comment: The people who closed this are clueless about networking. Good job guys!

Comment: There's a good reason this question exists. The kernel does not give us the same amount of packet throughput as the user API does. I honestly would appeal to @Makoto, John Palmer, Don Roby, rene, Ben about this.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using solarflare, you can use their API to do kernel bypass (I am not using it directly, so can't provide more details). You can also use a messaging broduct like 29West LBM or IBM LLM which support rich functionality over various hardware.

As @eSniff mentioned, the JRE has `transferFrom()` / `transferTo()` API which right now is used to expose the `sendfile(2)` equivalent for the systems that support it. The semantics of the API is defined so it can be transparently implemented to support DMA transfers between any 2 channels.

Comment: Hey, but transferFrom and transferTo have to do with FileChannel! I am talking about SocketChannel and DatagramChannel here for networking :(

Comment: @chrisapotek a socketChannel is both a WritableByteChannel and a ReadableByteChannel, so ....  someFileChannel.transferFrom(someSocketChannel, pos, count ) / someFileChannel.transferTo( pos, count, someSocketChannel)   I've only used the Netty wrappers myself, but this should work.

Comment: The transferXxx is the standard API for exposing DMA-style functionality. In the Oracle HotSpot JRE, as of version 7, it is implemented only for files and sockets. I don't think it would work between user-space memory buffer and socket (i.e. RDMA). That said, the code has extension points and if I am not mistaken, new channel types can be added by provider libraries by 3rd parties.

Answer (score 3):

Search for "Java Zero-Copy Buffers" or "Java NIO" or "Java Netty".

Here is a slide show about [Netty](https://netty.io/) and zero-copy : http://www.slideshare.net/danbim/zerocopy-eventdriven-servers-with-netty .  Here is an example project with Netty.

Or you can go lower level and use the [java.nio.channels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html) classes, which you can read about here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/j-zerocopy/

Comment: That's great info eSniff. I am using Java NIO but that does not bypass the kernel.

Comment: I haven't programed in java in years so I'm not sure how relevant the answer is any more.   But why the downvotes recently?